# How to use forms to update SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms

I'm trying to make a form that uses a drop down, radio buttons, text field, textarea, and a hidden value(the time) then takes that information from that form and updates SQL database.

My form is below and it all loads correctly but I'm having issues updating the values and trying to figure out how to make the radio buttons and dropdowns to work since I can't make the value php code and need to pass the value. Everything I'm finding on the web is how to do text fields where the user types something.

When I select update it just submits the data but nothing changes. On my update.php I have a sanitize function at the very end and am unsure how to pass the variables in. Do I create an array named $var and input all my variables into it or pass each variable at a time?

I've been searching the web for HOW TO's and am currently reading two books but they don't go into enough detail so thanks for any assistance.

control.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if( !isset($_SESSION['myusername']) ){ header("Location: login.php"); }
 ?> 

 <?php 
 require("../../system/templates/includes/constants.php");
 $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 if(!$connection) { die("Database connection failed: " .mysql_error()); }
 $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
 if(!$db_select) { die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error()); }
 ?>

<form method="post" action="update.php">
<select name="name" required="true" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
<?php                         
$query="SELECT id, name FROM modules";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<br />
Select Status:
Red    <input type="radio" value="red" name="status" />
Yellow    <input type="radio" value="yellow" name="status" />
Green    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="green" name="status" />
<br />
Reason:
<br />
<select name="reason" required="true">
<option value="0" selected="selected" value="">Select Reason</option>
<option value="ONLINE">Online</option>
<option value="MAINTENANCE">Maintenance</option>
<option value="ERROR">Error</option>
<option value="OFFLINE">Offline</option>
<option value="">No Reason</option>
</select>
<br />
ETA:
<br />
<input type="text" name="eta" value="<?php echo $row['eta']; ?>" maxlength="8" />
<br />
Description:
<br />
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="explanation" wrap="hard" required="true" maxlength="320" value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>" /></textarea>
<br />
<div align="right">
<input name="update" type="submit" value="Update"/>
<input type="hidden" name="last_updated" value="<?php $mysqldate = date ('H:i');  $phpdate = strtotime ( $mysqldate );?> />
 </form>
```

update.php

```
<?php
print_r(_POST);
if(isset($POST['update']))
{
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if(! $connection) 
{
die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}
$name = $POST['name'];
$status = $POST['status'];
$reason = $POST['reason'];
$eta = $POST['eta'];
$description = $POST['description'];
$last_updated = $POST['last_updated'];
$updated_by = $POST['updated_by'];
$sql = "UPDATE module SET status = $status , reason = $reason , eta = $eta , description = $description , last_updated = $last_updated , updated_by = $updated_by WHERE name = $name";
mysql_select_db('status');
$retval = mysql_query ( $sql, $connection);
if (!retval)
{
die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully";
mysql_close($connection);
} else {
// not sure what to do here
}
function sanitizeString($var)
{
$var = stripslashes($var);
$var = htmlentities($var);
$var = strip_tags($var);
return $var;
}
function sanitizeMySQL($var)
{
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
$var = satnizeString($var);
return $var;
}
header("Location: control.php");
?>
```

As always I greatly appreciate any assistance anyone can offer. I'm still in the very early stages of learning this and this website and community has helped me more than any book/tutorial I've read so far.

Comment: Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It takes care of sanitizing data.

Comment: Reading and trying to convert all my code to PDO. If I do this and am still having issues will probably close this question and remake it since the code will had drastically changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement needs quotation marks for each parameter.

```
$sql = "UPDATE module SET status = '$status' , reason = '$reason' , eta = '$eta' , description = '$description' , last_updated = '$last_updated' , updated_by = '$updated_by' WHERE name = '$name' ";
```

As for the `sanitizeString()` function, it only takes in one string at a time. Maybe something like the one below may be simple and clean:

```
$params = array($name, $status, $reason); // put all your params in here
foreach ($params as &$p) { // the '&' before $p is essential, so do not forget it
    $p = sanitizeString($p);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, added the ticks and it's still not updating the database. Edit: Thanks for the sanitize help as well, will take a look at it and see what I can do with it!

Comment: Hmm... are you getting any errors on the mysql_error() line, or any errors on your server's error log?

Comment: No errors unfortunately and not getting an update stating that the data has been updated. I also tried print_r(_POST) and that didn't do anything either.